# x11 dependency in a homebrew formula?

Tags: homebrew, x11

What is the correct way to specify x11 dependency in a homebrew formula?
The default superenv removes /opt/X11/lib from its arguments.

I am writing a formula for a package that I can build outside of homebrew with the usual configure, make install.

So I have this install function:

```
  def install
        ENV["PKG_CONFIG_PATH"] = "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/pkgconfig"
        # ENV["PATH"] = "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin" <--- work around
        Dir.chdir("codebase")
        system "./configure", "--disable-dependency-tracking", "--prefix=#{prefix}"
        system "make install"    
  end
```

The link phase that gets echoed shows

```
/bin/sh ../../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link clang++ .... -I /opt/X11/include ..... -L/opt/X11/lib ...
```

But the link fails with

```
 ld: library not found for -lX11
```

If I add this to the top of the class definition, the build is successful
`env :std`

Alternatively, I can set PATH inside the build function and the build succeeds.

This makes sense since within the context of `brew install`, **/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super** appears at the start of the PATH, and that directory has a clang++ which among other things strips /opt/X11 components out.

I assume there is a good reason for this behavior, and am curious what is the best way to specify that X11 library.

Comment: What about using `depends_on :x11` as in the formula `gv.rb`?

Comment: Lower case 'x' is the ticket.  I was trying `depends_on :X11`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to know how to do something in writing Hombrew formulas is to look at existing formulas. For your case you can look at [`MuPDF`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mupdf.rb) a lightweight PDF and XPS viewer depending on X11. In its formula you will find the solution:

```
depends_on :x11
```

Comment: Looks like this doesn;t worx since brew removed x11 formula... any suggestion?

Comment: I've updated my answer with MuPDF. This formula doesn't depend on the `x11` formula but on `:x11` which is a special kind of dependencies. See [depends_on.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/bada451a813031a0c7e5f063bea4358ecff5b2c6/Library/Homebrew/cask/dsl/depends_on.rb)

Comment: It seems that `:x11` has been deleted: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/d73351251cb90fcc353557e6dfd4497a6ad83aef#diff-bc8826114535861135fe0a441ee1441d9d6e0c2577ed7a8f2f03c123b92c5efe. Now one should use `"libx11"`.